# What is wrong with this Fortran '77 snippet?

Tags: macos, fortran77, gfortran

I've been tasked with maintaing some legacy fortran code, and I'm having trouble getting it to compile with gfortran. I've written a fair amount of Fortran 95, but this is my first experience with Fortran 77. This snippet of code is the problematic one:

```
      CHARACTER*22 IFILE, OFILE
      IFILE='TEST.IN'
      OFILE='TEST.OUT'
      OPEN(5,FILE=IFILE,STATUS='NEW')   
      OPEN(6,FILE=OFILE,STATUS='NEW')
      common/pabcde/nfghi
```

When I compile with `gfortran file.FOR`, all lines starting with the `common` statement are errors (e.g. `Error: Unexpected COMMON statement at (1)` for each following line until it hits the 25 error limit). I compiled with `-Wall -pedantic`, but fixing the warnings did not fix this problem.

The crazy thing is that if I comment out **all 4** lines starting with `IF='TEST.IN'`, the program compiles and works as expected, but *I must comment out all of them*. Leaving any of them uncommented gives me the same errors starting with the `common` statement. If I comment out the `common` statement, I get the same errors, just starting on the following line.

I am on OS X Leopard (not Snow Leopard) using `gfortran`. I've used this very system with `gfortran` extensively to write Fortran 95 programs, so in theory the compiler itself is sane. What the hell is going on with this code?

---

**Edit**: Compiling with g77 gives:

```
test.FOR: In program `MAIN__':
test.FOR:154: 
     IFILE='TEST.IN'
     1
test.FOR:158: (continued):
     common/pabcde/nfghi
     2
Statement at (2) invalid in context established by statement at (1)
```

Er, what context is established at (1)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can put `COMMON` statements below the executable statements in FORTRAN 77, see [the specification](http://www.fortran.com/F77_std/rjcnf0001-sh-3.html), Sec. 3.5.
Just move the `COMMON` statement close to the beginning of the procedure, before any executable statement.

Comment: Ahh, of course. I kind of thought of that, but I needed to move the executable statements waaay down, and didn't move them far enough initially. Reading the spec helped decipher some other errors I was getting, too.